# C# reading joystick input without blocking UI

Tags: c#, asynchronous, joystick

This will probably sound strange for some of you, but I can not figure out right way to read joystick input without blocking my UI form. I have found this example on internet:

```
static void Main()
{
    // Initialize DirectInput
    var directInput = new DirectInput();

    // Find a Joystick Guid
    var joystickGuid = Guid.Empty;

    foreach (var deviceInstance in directInput.GetDevices(DeviceType.Gamepad, 
                DeviceEnumerationFlags.AllDevices))
        joystickGuid = deviceInstance.InstanceGuid;

    // If Gamepad not found, look for a Joystick
    if (joystickGuid == Guid.Empty)
        foreach (var deviceInstance in directInput.GetDevices(DeviceType.Joystick, 
                DeviceEnumerationFlags.AllDevices))
            joystickGuid = deviceInstance.InstanceGuid;

    // If Joystick not found, throws an error
    if (joystickGuid == Guid.Empty)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No joystick/Gamepad found.");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }

    // Instantiate the joystick
    var joystick = new Joystick(directInput, joystickGuid);

    Console.WriteLine("Found Joystick/Gamepad with GUID: {0}", joystickGuid);

    //Query all suported ForceFeedback effects
    var allEffects = joystick.GetEffects();
    foreach (var effectInfo in allEffects)
        Console.WriteLine("Effect available {0}", effectInfo.Name);

    //Set BufferSize in order to use buffered data.
    joystick.Properties.BufferSize = 128;

    // Acquire the joystick
    joystick.Acquire();

    // Poll events from joystick
    while (true)
    {
        joystick.Poll();
        var datas = joystick.GetBufferedData();
        foreach (var state in datas)
            Console.WriteLine(state);
    }
}
```

I have installed sharpdx and I can see joystick axis output in console.

Now I want to display each axis data in separate textbox on my UI. So I changed few lines of code:

```
joystick.Poll();
var data = joystick.GetBufferedData();
foreach (var state in data) 
{
    if (state.Offset == JoystickOffset.X)
    {
       textBox1.Text = state.Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

So this should pass data to textbox. If I write here `Console.Writeline(state.Value)` I will get data I want to display. Problem is, that this `while loop` blocks UI.

I would like to put this while loop in `private void timer_tick` and set maybe 10 milliseconds refresh rate. But I don't know how to access variables like `var joystick` in separate function. I have also read that this can be done with asynchronous programming. Sadly I am stuck now.

Can anybody help me with as simple solution as possible to this problem? Code example would be great.

Comment: I might have an answer, but I'm not a C# developer. The variable data is an array of elements, and in the foreach loop the variable 'state' is the element of that iteration. Is it right?

Comment: is it WinForm or WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you code with WinForm (deduced from `blocking my UI form` in your question).

Add a timer to your Form from the designer.

And add these lines in the Form's .ctor:

```
public partial class JoyStickForm : Form
{
    public JoyStickForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // ...Other initialization code has been stripped...

        // Instantiate the joystick
        var joystick = new Joystick(directInput, joystickGuid);

        //Console.WriteLine("Found Joystick/Gamepad with GUID: {0}", joystickGuid);

        timer1.Interval = 100; 
        timer1.Tick += (s, e) =>
            {
                joystick.Poll();
                var lastState = joystick.GetBufferedData().Last(); //only show the last state

                if (lastState != null)
                {
                    if (lastState.Offset == JoystickOffset.X)
                    {
                        textBox1.Text = lastState.Value.ToString();
                    }
                }
            };

        //start the timer
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Explanations:

1. A refreshing rate of 100 times per second is unnecessarily fast, remember the refreshing rate of most monitors is about 60 Hz. I set it as 100 ms (10 refreshes per second), which is acceptable.
2. Using [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx), you have access to the variables like `var joystick` from the timer's tick handler.
3. In each freshing, only the last state in the data is displayed to the `TextBox`.